# Simple one Line str_replace

Tags: php, str-replace

I'm trying to work out how to replace a word in my website script that I run on a file import to clean up the data.

In my example I want to replace the Subcategory called "Seeds" to now be called "Plants & Seeds"

At the moment it looks like this:

```
[str_replace('Seeds','Plants & Seeds',{subcategory[1]})]
```

But that will also replace other Sub categories that also have the word "Seeds"

I have tried the following both without success( basically wild guessing):

```
[str_replace(':Seeds', '"Plants & Seeds"',{subcategory[1]})]

[str_replace($Seeds, "Plants & Seeds",{subcategory[1]})]
```

This must be on one line to work in my field with the import script on the website.

How could I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$subcategory[1]="Seeds .. blablabla Seeds 2 Seeds 3 Seeds4";
echo preg_replace('/Seeds/', 'Plants & Seeds', $subcategory[1], 1); 
//Plants & Seeds .. blablabla Seeds 2 Seeds 3 Seeds4
```

have a nice day ;)

**EDIT**

```
$subcategory[1]="Seeds .. blablabla Seeds 2 Seeds 3 Seeds4, Pots Planters & Tools, Pots, Planters & Tools";
$seed_replaced=preg_replace('/Seeds/', 'Plants & Seeds', $subcategory[1], 1); 
$Pots_Planters_one=preg_replace('/Pots Planters & Tools/', 'Pots & Planters', $seed_replaced, 1); 
$all_replaced=preg_replace('/Pots, Planters & Tools/', 'Pots & Planters', $Pots_Planters_one, 1); 
echo $all_replaced;
//Plants & Seeds .. blablabla Seeds 2 Seeds 3 Seeds4, Pots & Planters, Pots & Planters
```

Comment: thanks, I try to run this as I also want to replace some other data: [preg_replace(array('/Seeds/', 'Pots Planters & Tools', 'Pots, Planters & Tools'), array('Plants & Seeds', 'Pots & Planters', 'Pots & Planters'), {subcategory[1]})] ............ but then I get this error mesge:  warning-preg_replace-function-preg-replace-delimiter-must-not-be-alphanumeric-or-backslash-in- (my website directory)

Comment: you can´t use array inside preg_replace, make it easy, use 3 times the same function.. chek the edit.

Comment: Thanks, I see that but I'm not sure how I can get this to work for my website as it all needs to be on ONE LINE as it goes into a form field on my website and then processed through a script run from that form on the server?

Comment: i guess my original question was answered, perhaps I should start a new topic since I wanted to add 2 X more conditions to the code and that is where it gets tricky now?